# Allowing a user to resize a GWT TextArea using "gripper bars"

Tags: gwt

I am currently trying to replicate the functionality of the Sticky application [(fourth example under "samples")](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/examples/) in my GWT application, specifically NoteView (see the class NoteView in SurfaceView.java [in my personal repo](https://bitbucket.org/duac/sticky/changeset/7f3dabf8a68e#chg-src/com/google/appengine/demos/sticky/client/SurfaceView.java) or download Google App Engine's SDK, where you'll find it in appengine-java-sdk-1.5.1/demos/sticky).

However, as hard as I try, I just cannot find the place where Google put in the gripper bars on the bottom right hand corner of every note, and where their code allowed the user to resize the note. grepping for "resize" and "resizable" in their sticky dir was not fruitful, and the CSS "resize" functionality was not used either. Also, GWT Textareas are not automatically resizable in the way that these notes in GWT are, and I don't know how to enable this or set it up.

Comment: The repo is now public. Sorry about the second link not working earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out -- it was old crud css left over from a gxt implementation. As soon as I removed the css file, the textarea automatically had gripper bars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but it really just is a textarea, and your browser does the rest (most browsers make textareas resizable nowadays).

Using Firebug or a similar developer tool, can you tell which differences are there between the Sticky sample and what your code does?

Comment: The sticky code has <textarea class="note-content" tabindex="0" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;"></textarea> and I have <textarea class="note-content" tabindex="0" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;"></textarea>. They are exactly the same.